# If a project's git repo was archived and re-initialized is it possible to combine the old and new repos?

Tags: git

Apologies if the title of my question doesn't quite make sense.  I'm trying to avoid words that are overloaded like "how do I merge two git repos".

Here's a more elaborate description of my question:

I'm working on a project that is several years old; however the current git repo only has a few months of history.  The first commit was a large one which effectively committed a full `git archive` of the previous repository.

I'd like to try to recombine these different git repositories and salvage as much of the project's history as possible; is there a tool, or a tutorial, that could help me with the process?

Here's a quick diagram to help further

oldRepo

```
    * Commit 1 - added file A
    * Commit 2 - edited file A
    * Commit 3 - added file B
    * Commit 4 - edited file B
```

newRepo

```
    * Commit 1 - added all contents from oldRepo at Commit 4
    * Commit 2 - added file C
    * Commit 3 - edited file C
```

combined Repo

```
    * Commit 1 - (from oldRepo) - added file A
    * Commit 2 - (from oldRepo) - edited file A
    * Commit 3 - (from oldRepo) - added file B
    * Commit 4 - (from oldRepo) - edited file B
    * Commit 5 - (from newRepo) - added file C
    * Commit 6 - (from newRepo) - edited file C
```

Comment: See this question: sounds like what you are trying to do: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1425892/how-do-you-merge-two-git-repositories

Comment: That looks close, but is most geared to bring two different projects into a single repository.  I'll try what was outlined here http://stackoverflow.com/a/8188110/60724 as it seems to match my case